# If a request hit to my socket at '/' route this function gets executed is it posiible to execute this code async?

Tags: javascript, node.js

exports.check= function(fn){

```
process.nextTick(function(){
while (true) {
    setTimeout(function(){iconsole.log('what');fn(1)},15000)
    console.log('ok')
}
})
```

}

Comment: This code already is async. What are you asking for? Please show us your socket code as well that calls this function, it will need to account for asynchrony.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute this code async"?  What is that code supposed to do?  Step back a level and describe your actual problem.

Comment: This code blocks my main thread beacause of this while loop, my main question is how to use while loop in node.js to to posix operation through nodejs or async operation

Comment: When this loop gets execute, it register a event but event never gets called.

Comment: Yes, because the loop doesn't stop executing. What do you think `while(true)` does?

Comment: it means it is a blocking event loop, no events after this loop going to be called. so how to use while loop to make a code async or non-blocking without any spawning or forking, is it possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path');

var app = express();
tt=require('./tt')
app.get('/test',function(req,res){
 tt.check(function(err,data){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
    if(err){res.status(500).json({error : err})}
    else{res.send(data)}
})
})

and check function is defined in my question.
```